# Syntax error when trying to create a BEFORE INSERT trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
CREATE TRIGGER age_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON kids FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF (NEW.age < 0) THEN SET NEW.age = NEW.age * -1;
END IF;
END;
```

I am getting an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '' at line 5

I have tried removing the if/else, hardcoding `NEW.AGE = 50`, and looked at examples online. My syntax matches online examples, but I keep getting the same error. I don't believe its my version of MySQL. Thoughts?

Comment: Apart from `DELIMITER   // `   `.... //`   `DELIMITER ;` it looks fine to my inexperienced eyes.

Comment: @JoopEggen Ah, I missed that! It works now, thank you so much!